# jQuery Toggle Expand only if hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with an "Expand All" link that should expand the list ONLY if it is hidden.  What I have now is that it checks whether or not the first list is expanded only.  For example, if list 1's list is expanded, and you press expand all, it will toggle the list, hidding it while list 2 properly shows.  I haven't been able to figure out how to toggle only if hidden.  Vice versa, for the Hide all button, it should hide all expanded lists.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/dp5c3uLp/2/

```js
$(function(){
  $("li.one").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.expand").toggle('slow');
  });

  $("p.expand").click(function(){
    if($("div.expand").css("display")=="none"){
      $("div.expand").show('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li.one a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expand"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Expand All]</a></p>
<p class="hide"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Hide All]</a></p>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>1(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>2(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to find the hidden div you just show all `div.expand` because as my thought `expand all` mean you want to show all `div.expand`

here is snippet just try this:

```js
$(function(){
$("li.one").click(function(){
 $(this).next("div.expand").toggle('slow');
});
$("p.expand").click(function(){
  $("div.expand").show('slow');  
});
$("p.hide").click(function(){
 $("div.expand").hide('slow');  
});
});
```

```css
li.one a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expand"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Expand All]</a></p>
<p class="hide"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Hide All]</a></p>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>1(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>2(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("div.expand").is(':hidden')) { ... }
```

or select only hidden divs with this selector:

```
$("div.expand:hidden")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector.

```js
$(function(){
  $("li.one").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.expand").not(":visible").toggle('slow');
  });

  $("p.expand").click(function(){
    if($("div.expand").css("display")=="none"){
      $("div.expand").show('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li.one a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expand"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Expand All]</a></p>
<p class="hide"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Hide All]</a></p>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>1(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>2(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `hidden` filter instead

```js
$(function(){
  $("li.one").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.expand").toggle('slow');
  });

  $("p.expand").click(function(){
    if($("div.expand").is(":hidden")){
      $("div.expand").show('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li.one a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expand"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Expand All]</a></p>
<p class="hide"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>[Hide All]</a></p>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>1(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>

<li class="one"><a href="" onclick='return false;'>2(Expand Me)</a></li>
<div class="expand" style="display:none;">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</div>
```